# crear un archivo almacenar información y mostrar dicha información en un Arraylist

Tags: java

Crear un archivo con la información de sus datos personales, empleando la escritura de archivos, lectura.
Implemente las clases necesarias.
Controlar al menos una excepción.
Implemente el uso de una colección de datos que almacene los datos recuperados del archivo y muéstrelos mediante el uso de un iterador.

esto es el poco codigo que voy:

```
public class Tarea_u34_poo
 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         datospersonales d1 = new datospersonales();
       
            d1 = leerdatos();

            guardar(d1);

        leer();

        

    }//Aquí termina main

    public static datospersonales leerdatos() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        datospersonales datos1 = new datospersonales();
        System.out.println("Ingrese la cedula:");
        datos1.setCedula(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Ingrese los nombre:");
        datos1.setNombre(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Ingrese los apellidos:");
        datos1.setApellido(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Ingrese la edad:");
        datos1.setEdad(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Ingrese la carrera:");
        datos1.setCarrera(sc.nextLine());
        return datos1;
    }

    public static void guardar(datospersonales e) {
        escri_dato escribir = new escri_dato();
        escribir.escribir("datospersonales.txt", e);
    }

    public static void leer() {
        lectu_datos leer = new lectu_datos();
        leer.leer("datospersonales.txt");
    }
    
         
    }
```

en esta parte esta un clase con un método para escribir que sirve para escribir la información en el archivo

```
public class escri_dato {
    public void escribir( String nombreArchivo, datospersonales datos)
    {System.out.println("Escribiendo la informacón del archivo");
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(nombreArchivo,true);
            BufferedWriter archivoescritura = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            String almacenar= datos.toString();
            archivoescritura.write(almacenar);
            archivoescritura.flush();
            archivoescritura.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

en esta otra parte esta el metodo lectura que es el método que uso para leer la información e imprimirla

```
public class lectu_datos {
     public void leer(String nombrearchivo) {
        String cadeleida = "";
        FileReader fr;

        try {
            fr = new FileReader(nombrearchivo);
            BufferedReader archivolectura = new BufferedReader(fr);
            datospersonales d2 = new datospersonales();
            System.out.println("Mis datos personales son:");
            cadeleida = archivolectura.readLine();
            while (cadeleida != null) {
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(cadeleida, ",");
                d2.setCedula(st.nextToken());
                d2.setNombre(st.nextToken());
                d2.setApellido(st.nextToken());
                d2.setEdad(st.nextToken());
                d2.setCarrera(st.nextToken());
                System.out.print(d2);
                cadeleida = archivolectura.readLine();
            }
            archivolectura.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("No se pudo localizar el archivo.\n" + e.toString());
           e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("No se pudo leer el arhivo.\n" + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

lo que me haria falta es un metodo con el cual pueda leer la informacion del arcvhivo ya creado y ponerlo en un arraylist

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta y/o el problema que estás teniendo? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: lo que pasa es que necesito almacenar la información de un archivo txt dentro de un arraylist pero no se como

Comment: @FernandoJosueMeroBriones Lo recomendable es agregar las clases escri_dato y lectu_datos  para ver como las tienes,  agregué una respuesta, saludos.

Comment: ya lo edite, perdón soy nuevo en esto @Jorgesys

Answer (score 3):

Solo modifica tu clase para escribir los datos, la cual tendrá un método para recibir el nombre del archivo y el objeto `datospersonales`  :

```
import java.io.FileWriter; 
import java.io.IOException;

public class escri_dato {

    void escribir(String filename, datospersonales datos) {
        try {
            FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(filename);
            myWriter.write(datos.getApellido()+"\n");
            myWriter.write(datos.getNombre()+"\n");
            myWriter.write(datos.getEdad()+"\n");
            myWriter.write(datos.getCedula()+"\n");
            myWriter.write(datos.getCarrera()+"\n");
            myWriter.close();            
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred." + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Mientras que la clase para leer los datos tendrá un método que recibirá el nombre del archivo extraerá los datos y los mostrará en pantalla.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class lectu_datos {

    void leer(String filename) {
        try {
            File myObj = new File(filename);
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = myReader.nextLine();
                System.out.println(data);
            }
            myReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```